# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I make simply rss reader in android. I have the errors (I searched and tried some solutions but nothing):

```
Couldn't open http://pogoda.wp.pl/rss.xml
java.io.IOException: Couldn't open http://pogoda.wp.pl/rss.xml
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.openUrl(ExpatParser.java:755)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:292)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:390)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:266)
at com.newsreader.RssReader.getItems(RssReader.java:23)
at com.newsreader.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.openUrl(ExpatParser.java:753)
```

and activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    RssReader reader = new RssReader("http://pogoda.wp.pl/rss.xml");
                    ListView items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, reader.getItems());
                    items.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.i("", ""+reader);
                    items.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(reader.getItems(), MainActivity.this));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("blad", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }

                }

        });
        }
    }.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}

 }
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Maybe someone has got the same problem so please help. 
Thanks

Comment: `RssReader reader = new RssReader("http://pogoda.wp.pl/rss.xml");` probably should be in a thread and there is no need for `runOnUiThread`

Comment: try to use asynctask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: So, Google Search is not working for you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: What do you think `runOnUiThread()` does?

Comment: @laalto but it is inside a new thread! *scnr* :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Always use `AsyncTask` to solve this issue.

**BUT**, if you're within the movie [Swordfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordfish_%28film%29), someone points a gun at you and say "fix it in 30 seconds", then change your `targetSdkVersion` to **9** in the `Android Manifest` and the exception will stop. Don't worry, it will run on devices with version higher than 9 too. Even so, correct your code later using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: don't you think changing target sdk version to 9 will restrict the app to only around 25% of android devices?

Comment: @VishwasSharma `targetSdkVersion` doesn't restrict the app to only version 9. It only shows that the app was explicitly tested to that version. But this solution is only for someone that really needs to correct the problem as fast as possible.

Comment: it'll eliminate the exception, but will it run on devices having sdk version higher than 9?

Comment: @VishwasSharma Yes, exactly. It'll run on devices with sdk version higher than 9, for sure.

Comment: ok, never tested it that way

Comment: @VishwasSharma I don't use it anymore, but was very usefull one time, when the app was already deployed and we changed the `targetSdkVersion` just before the deploy.

Comment: refactoring the code to use AsyncTask might take 5 minutes. So unless you are within the movie Swordfish where someone points a gun at you and say: "fix it in 30 seconds", there will never be an emergency big enough to just change the targetSdkVersion... also you will get the ["Menu button of shame!"](https://www.google.de/search?q=menu+button+of+shame)

Comment: I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are performing network operation on main thread of activity. Using **Async task** will be a better option.

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: It **should not** be a comment.

Comment: @Andrain the question asker might be knowing how to user async task, or he can ask for code. Now how can i post code in comments if needed and btw this is my answer

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

This speaks for itself.

**Don't do** networking on the main Thread!

`AsyncTask` to the rescue. Try it out it will work.